# How to find intersecting rows in two tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two unequal length 2d tensors in tensorflow and I have to find the 1d boolean tensor that gives information if rows of the first tensor are present in the second.
For example: if tensor1 = [[0,1,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,2]] and tensor2 = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]], then the 1d tensor should be [True, False, False].

I have tried this with tf.equal() function using broadcasting but it takes up a lot of memory. I want this function to be time and memory-optimized because the tensors are very large. Could somebody recommend any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the tensor to find the rows of the first tensor are present in the second.

For example, i have taken 2 tensors

```
tensor1 =tf.constant([[0,1,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,2]])
tensor2 = tf.constant([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]])
```

Iterate first tensor over the second one to the rows of the first tensor are  present in the second

```
for i in range(len(tensor1)):
  print(tensor1[i].numpy()==tensor2.numpy())
```

The output of above code will be

```
[[ True False False]
 [ True False  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [False  True  True]]
[[ True False  True]
 [ True False False]
 [ True  True False]
 [False  True False]]
[[ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [ True  True False]
 [False  True False]]
```

Thank You.